# Proving Lebesgue integral statements

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu )$ be a measure space. If $f: X \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb R}$ is measurable and $\int |f| \, d \mu < \infty$, then:

- for any $a>0$, the set $\{x \in X : |f(x)|>a \}$ has finite measure
- the set $\{x \in X: f(x) \neq 0\}$ has $\sigma$-finite measure, i.e. is a countable union of sets of finite measure.

I am really trying to learn this myself and I would love to see how these two statements would be proved.

Please can someone help me.

Comment: For the first one, argue by contradiction.

Comment: im still not sure, would you be able to show me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$ Assume that the set $A = \{ x \in X : |f(x)| > a \}$ has infinite measure, then we have
$$\int_X|f| \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_A|f|\mathrm{d}\mu + \int_{A^c}|f|\mathrm{d}\mu \geq \int_A |f|\mathrm{d}\mu \geq a\cdot\mu(A) = \infty$$
which is contradiction to our hypothesis that $f$ is integrable.

$2)$ See the answer by user46944.

Comment: what does * mean?

Comment: Ordinary multiplication, but I changed to an unambiguous symbol/

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Nigel got part $1$.  For part $2$,

$\{x \mid f(x) \neq 0\} = \{ x \mid |f(x)| \neq 0 \} = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \{x \mid |f(x)| > \frac{1}{n} \}$.  Of course, you should prove that these two sets are equal, but once you do, each of the sets in the union has finite measure by part $1$, and thus the set $\{ x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \}$ is $\sigma$-finite.